# Linear Algebra - Matrix not Invertible - governing DOF

Tags: inverse, numerical-linear-algebra

I am an engineer working on a structural engineering analysis problem. It is quite simple: I have a 3x3 Matrix representing the stiffness of a 2D-structure (with the three degrees of freedom: 
displacement in x-direction $u_x$, 
displacement in y-direction $u_y$ and
rotation about z -axis $\varphi_z$).

The Matrix $K$ represents the Stiffness. With a given force vector $F=\{{f_x;f_y;\varphi_z}\}$. The displacement vector $U$ is calculated from $U=K^{-1}\cdot F$.

Now in some cases $K$ is not invertible, and I would like to find the degree of freedom, that is responsible for that. The structure may be kinematic in one direction or the rotation.
I know, that K is not invertible, if $det[K]=0$ or near $0$. But how do I calculate the eigenform using Singular Value Decomposition?

An example:

[image: a) K is invertibla b) not invertible]

Thank You and sorry for my poor mathematic knowledge.

Comment: You do not need an SVD (I also assume you want to do this by hand). Just compute [REF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form) of your stiffness matrix and check where you get a "missing step".

Comment: Thank You Pavel, I did an eigenvert calculation and found the rank of the matrix and the first eigenvalue and first Eigenvector as the one, that shows the degree of freedom. Yout Comment is however valuable for me. I might end up deleting the question - what Do You think?